# Turn off highlights

Tags: phpstorm

I want to turn off PHPStorm's annoying highlighting for non-error related things.

[image]

I read their docs, which said to go to preferences->editor->inspections. I deselected all for SQL, yet I still get this green highlighting for no reason:

[image]

How do I disable this? It's quite distracting.

Comment: That's Language Injection -- you can either remove that background color in Editor's Color Scheme .. or just disable that particular injection rule (but then you will loose helpers for SQL code).

Comment: I don't see the Color Scheme option in Editor.

Comment: `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General`

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks! Post as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's **Language Injection** in action.

You can:

- Remove/change background color at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General --> Code | Injected language fragment`
- Disable that particular injection rule altogether at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Editor | Language Injections`

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks @LazyOne

Comment: Thanks! It was really annoying!

Comment: Lazy One I feel you have saved me before. Up-voted and MUCH appreciated (after about a year of looking!). Steve