# IntelliJ IDEA: turn off highlight for language injection

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm using [style-jsx](https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx) library for styling css. I also use IntelliJ IDEA language injection for coding highlight. But IntelliJ IDEA highlights all my code.

How can I turn this feature off?

Here is the sample image:

[image]

Comment: So .. you want to remove that green background? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30784708/783119

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the green background, you can change the color in `Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General / Code / Injected language fragment settings`, `Background`.